# How to pass the custom object to remote stream in agora web

Tags: agora.io

I am working in agora web 3.x. I want to pass the custom javascript object from localstream to remote user object.so remote user can access that object

Comment: Can you please clarify on the feature that you are looking to implement? Also provide nay code you have written.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Agora RTM SDK](https://docs.agora.io/en/Real-time-Messaging/landing-page) for web to send and recieve data between users on the same channel. You can convert your JS Object to a JSON and send it over RTM.